# A phrase as an interjection

Tags: punctuation, sentence-patterns

Often in spoken English, I see one sentence or phrase "set up" another much like an interjection.  For example:

> I forgot to ask.  Did you find that book I told you about?

How do you generally punctuate this?  I've seen a comma used for this, but I that's only correct if it can be argued that *I forgot to ask* is a proper interjection (can it be?).

Should I use a colon?  Semi-colon?  Does it matter?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/is-it-a-splice-comma-if-an-interjection-phrase-is-involved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could punctuate this in a few ways, in decreasing levels of formality

With a [colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29) (:)

> I forgot to ask: did you find that book I told you about?

With a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (–)

> I forgot to ask—did you find that book I told you about?

With an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (…)

> I forgot to ask…did you find that book I told you about?

The colon is the most formal, the ellipsis quite informal. I personally would use a dash. The ellipsis here is used to indicate a pause or an unfinished thought, which some purists might object to (claiming that an ellipsis can only be used to indicate something which has been left out).

Answer (score 8):

You can certainly use a colon.

> I forgot to ask: did you find that book I told you about?

Technically, using a semi-colon would not be grammatically incorrect (both parts being complete sentences), but it wouldn't really fit the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a comma:

> I forgot to ask, 'Did you find that book I told you about?' (comma, direct speech)

One could rewrite it using indirect speech as well:

> I forgot to ask whether you found that book I told you about (indirect speech)